# How to flip/mirror a PIXI Graphics instance (drawRoundedRect)

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

I'm animating the height of a drawRoundedRect instance, however, because it starts drawing from the upper left corner, it's animating from top to bottom, and I need it to start from the bottom.

Is it possible to flip my graphics instance (I tried by setting the scale to inverse, but this doesn't render anything, perhaps it only works on sprites), or to start drawing a rounded rectangle from the bottom?

**EDIT**:

Okay so I found out it's possible to animate my height going in to the other direction by just multiplying my interpolated value by -1:

```
graphics.drawRoundedRect(
        x,
        y,
        barsWidth,
        interpolatedHeight * -1,
        10
);
```

However, now the radius isn't working anymore, it's just drawing square rectangles..

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure that I did understand the question but if a got it right, all you need to do is to change the pivot of the rectangle you are animating. In your case, `pivot.y` should be equal to the rectangle's height `rectangle.pivot.y = rectangle.height`. After you change the pivot you also need to position it /the rectangle/ accordingly, so it could retain its visual position `rectangle.y += rectangle.pivot.y`

a simple demo https://jsfiddle.net/4L1od09n/23/